# SQL to sort numbers within each row

Tags: sql, sqlite

What SQL select query can I use to sort integer numbers in each row?

E.g.: table t (n1, n2, n3, n4, n5, n6, n7)

```
2, 4, 3, 1, 9, 8, 5
10, 7, 11, 4, 3, 8, 6
```

The query must give

```
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 8, 9
3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 10, 11
```

Note that if I do it in application layer the process will take too much time because I have millions rows. So I hope by sorting those numbers in each row in the database would speed up the process.
Thank you for your kind help.

Comment: In general, if you need to sort numbers within a row, you have the wrong data structure.  There isn't an easy way to do this.

Comment: Can you give me an example of data structure so that I can revise it to achieve the sorting? Thank's

Comment: Alas, even with the right data structure, SQLite doesn't quite have the right functions.  Can you consider switching to another database?  An alternative would be to insert them in sorted order, using triggers.

Comment: Ahh, I see what you mean by wrong data structure.

Comment: Can you please give me an example of using trigger before inserting that I can use for this problem? Thank's